# Reference my tkinter label object using a function outside of the class

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to change the configurations on one of my labels, but cannot figure out how to reference it in a function outside of the class. My goal is to crate a function that will be placed in a loop to check the value of "my_turn". Depending on the value of "my_turn", I want to change the configuration of "self.turn" label in the "TeamFrame" class, however I can't figure out how to reference it outside of the class.

```
class LoginScreen(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.create_image(0, 0, image=my_img, anchor="nw")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Connect", bg='burlywood3', activebackground='burlywood3', font="12",
                                command=lambda: login())
        self.button.grid(row=4, columnspan=3, pady=10)

        def login():
            my_name = self.entry.get()
            msg = str(my_name)
            client.send(msg.encode(FORMAT))
            self.destroy()
            root.title(f"Main Application - {my_name}")
            draft = MainApplication(root, my_name)
            draft.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            threading.Thread(target=start_app).start()


class MainApplication(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.create_image(0, 0, image=my_img, anchor="nw")
        self.team = TeamFrame(self, 1, 4, name)


class TeamFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, r, c, name):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.configure(bd=1, relief="ridge", bg='wheat3')
        self.grid(row=r, rowspan=2, column=c, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=tk.NE)
        self.turn = tk.Label(self, bg='wheat3', text=f"You are not on the clock.\n                      ",
                             fg='gray28', font='bold 12', disabledforeground='red3')
        self.turn.pack(pady=10)


def start_app():
    # threaded loop that check "my_turn" and update lists and execute additional game functions


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plr.sort_players(sort_method)
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(400, 300)
    root.title(f"Login")
    root.iconbitmap('football.ico')
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='field.gif')
    LoginScreen(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about configuring a widget outside of the class it was defined in, we don't need much more than a class with a single label, and enough extra code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was afraid that I might leave out too much. I edited my original post and made it smaller. Hopefully this is a more acceptable amount as it relates to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the instance of `MainApplication`, `draft`, to `start_app()`:

```py
threading.Thread(target=start_app, args=(draft,)).start()
```

Then you can access the required label via `main_app.team.turn` (`main_app` is the name of the new argument of `start_app()`) as below:

```py
def start_app(main_app):
    # do something
    main_app.team.turn['text'] = 'Hello'
    # do other stuff
```

Comment: Of course it’s that simple. I knew I had to be overlooking it. Thank you so much!!!!!